# How to stop/override a Jquery TimeOut function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout, notifications

I have a small jquery snippet that displays notification message at the top of the screen in response to user actions on a page. The notification is often displayed after Ajax actions with dynamic content inside it.

For example:

```
$("#mini-txt").html("Thank you!");
$("#mini").fadeIn("fast");
setTimeout(function() {$("#mini").animate({height: "hide", opacity: "hide"}, "medium");}, 3000);
```

The notification works well, except when a user does two or more actions in rapid succession, in which case the TimeOut function will confuse itself and the second message appears to come inside the previous 3000 milliseconds.

Is there a way to "kill" the previous notification if a new action is performed. I've got no problem with the actions/selectors, just the TimeOut function.... either stopping it or overriding it somehow. Or perhaps there's a better alternative for getting the message to linger on the screen for a few seconds before disappearing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First, you store the return value for the `setTimeout` function:

```
// Set the timeout
var timeout = setTimeout(function()
    {
        // Your function here
    }, 2000);
```

Then, when you're ready to kill the timeout...you just call `clearTimeout` with the stored value from the previous call to `setTimeout`.

```
// Then clearn the timeout
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: will it execute the timeout function after clearing?

Answer (score 7):

You can use **[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

> Stop the currently-running animation
>   on the matched elements.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery 1.4 has a built in method to handle delays for animations you can do something like this:

```
$("#mini-txt").html("Thank you!");
$("#mini").fadeIn("fast").delay(3000).animate({height: "hide", opacity: "hide"}, "medium");
```

And then later when you want to clean the animation queue you can do:

```
$("#mini").stop(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will clear timeout after function run with delay 500ms

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){

/* YOUR FUNCTION */

}, 500, function(){
   clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```