# Cancel/stop a timeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have some javascipt (jQuery) in which I'm fading in #myDiv when a button is clicked, and then fading it out again after 5 seconds by using a Timeout function. It works fine, but if a user clicks the button again before the fadeOut function inside my timeout runs, I need the timeout to stop and essentially start over again.

I'm thinking the answer will be to run a function first to clear the timeout, though I cannot make this work.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

  //need function here to stop the timeout if running

  $("#myDiv").fadeIn(slow);

  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut(slow);
  }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: Look at this post to find your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578628/how-to-stop-override-a-jquery-timeout-function

Comment: thanks for the link -- I did  lot of research and found more than just this link that dealt with stopping the Timeout, but I could not figure out how to actually run the timeout after storing it in the variable, so I posted this question in hopes of finding a complete solution i.e. how to store the Timeout as a variable and how to run the Timeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must clear the timeout if is already set:

```
var to = null;
$('button').on('click', function() {

  if(to){
     clearTimeout(to);
  }
  //need function here to stop the timeout if running

  $("#myDiv").fadeIn(slow);

  to = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut(slow);
  }, 5000);

});
```

The `clearTimeout()` function delete the timeout so if the user click twice on the button the first timeout is deleted and only the second instance will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using built in jQuery API methods alone:

```
$('button').on('click', function() { 
  $("#myDiv")
        .stop(true,true) // resets current animation queue
        .fadeIn('slow')
        .delay(5000)// delays anything in queue
        .fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Makes things a bit easier to read

References:

- [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)
- [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ozhwnjrq/)**</kbd>